# setTimeout blocks eventloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I was reading an article that stated that to create a nonblocking/asynchronous function, usage of `setTimeout` is crucial. And I thought that the function that is passed to `setTimeout` runs in the background. Then I read in another article that `setTimeout` does block the event loop when function is fired. So, I tried the following function to test.

```
function getit(cb) {
var i = 0;
 setTimeout(function() {
  while (i < 200000) { i++; console.log(i); }
  cb(i); 
 } , 1000); 
 console.log(i); 
}

getit(function(message) { console.log(message); });
```

Apparently, when 1000ms passes and it is time to execute the function, the thread is blocked and my browser freezes. My question is, if asynchronous code is not supposed to block the thread, how is that possible when the function is being executed when time elapses and not in the background? It seems like this is just a delay, but eventually, the function is going to be executed line by line and block the loop anyway. Is there something I'm missing or confused about?

Comment: `setTimeout()` queues up a function to be run later and doesn't block execution of the *current* function. It doesn't run the queued function in "the background" or create a new thread for it. (Given you are talking about your browser freezing, why the node.js tag?)

Comment: https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop/

Comment: But does it block the thread when it is executing as showing in the given code? I understand that it doesn't block the current execution but when it is time to execute the function inside the setTimeout does it block the thread? I couldn't execute other functions while this was running.

Comment: As long as your `while (i < 200000) { i++; console.log(i); }` loop is running, no other code can run.  That is a "blocking" `while` loop.  JS in a browser is single threaded (except webWorkers, but that's not what we're talking about here).  So, until you return from what you're doing, the next event (even a scheduled timer event) cannot run.

Comment: [This article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) may be of some help to you.

Comment: So, If I'm looping over 2m rows of mysql, and returning result at the end, the thread will be blocked until I return the result? If so, how is async is considered non blocking? Because it is going to be looping over the rows but until I return the results, the server wouldn't be able to handle any other requests. Sorry but I'm so lost.

Comment: Why would you be looping over 2 million rows? Can't you structure your SQL query to get just the rows you need? (Or is the result that you return to the caller actually including 2 million rows?)

Comment: Assuming you're talking about NodeJS for the issue on 2m MySQL rows. The asynchronous, non-blocking side of NodeJS applies only to those tasks that are "outside of your script". The wait for the MySQL server to fetch 2m rows is truly non-blocking. But when you get the resource back as a single collection, `console.log`-ing each row is going to block. In this case, you have to seek stream-base implementations so results come in small asynchronous parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to understand that JavaScript, under most contexts is **single-threaded**. Be it asynchronous or not, once your script start executing, it blocks everything.

Your example above therefore enters the busy while-loop after 1000ms and begin blocking other execution.

To overcome this, the busy block has to be broken down to "yield" (Java terminology) execution cycles for other tasks.

E.g.:

```js
    function getit(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            lessBlockingGetIt(cb);
        } , 1000);
    }
    
    // Note that this is only less blocking, and much slower
    function lessBlockingGetIt(cb) {
    
        // Instead of directly looping, we batch-loop with a setTimeout
        var numberOfTimes = 1000; // Reduced the size so it doesn't block like forever
        var batchSize = 10;
    
        function executeBatch(start) {
    
            // We use a zero-timeout function is achieve a "yield" behavior so other tasks in the event loop can execute
            setTimeout(function(){
                var i = start, j;
                for(j = 0; i < numberOfTimes && j < batchSize; i++, j++){
                    console.log(i);
                }
                if(i < numberOfTimes){
                    executeBatch(i);
                } else {
                    cb(i);
                    console.log(i);
                }
            }, 0);
    
        }
      
        // Start the recursion loop
        executeBatch(0);
    
    }
    
    getit(function(message) { console.log(message); });
```

However, you would notice the execution is much slower, and the browser is apparently less responsive than otherwise true multithreading.

To achieve real multithreading, you would need to use web workers http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I just confused JS with NodeJS apparently.  I thought the async idea applies to both sides. So just to clarify, if I used the same code over nodejs, my server thread will not be blocked?

Comment: If you run the exact same code, it **would** block. It blocks because while-looping many times with `console.log` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js execution model can be represented by the following code:

```
function main() {
   while(running) {
     var timerCb = getNextTimedoutCallback();
     if( timerCb ) timerCb(); // execute it

     var ioCb = getNextCompleteIOOperationCallback();
     if( ioCb ) ioCb(); // execute it
   }
}
```

Everything runs in single thread. IO operations run in worker threads and populate internal queue of completed IO operations. That `getNextCompleteIOOperationCallback();` just pulls completed operation from the queue.

In the same way `setTimeout()` simply pushes function alongside with its end time to the timers queue (ordered by end time). And `getNextTimedoutCallback()` pulls next expired timeout (if any).

As you see either timer function or IO callback can block the whole thing. 
That's known as [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking).